# Tryin to print list that contains int and str, but do not print integers

Tags: python

I am writing a code that prints common items from two lists

```
def compare_lists_same(list3, list4):
    common =[j for j in list4 if j in list3]
    return common
A = ['beef','chicken','steak','fish','plants', 1, 2]
B = ['plants','steak','cheese', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ignore_case = False
print('First list:'+str(A))
print('Second list'+str(B))
C = compare_lists_same (A,B)
print('The common items from the lists are'+str(C))
```

This prints "The common items from the lists are['plants', 'steak', 1, 2]"

How would I tell the function to print the list without the integers, so only str would be printed

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built in `isinstance` function:

```
str_only = [i for i in C if isinstance(i, str)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`output = [val for val in C if isinstance(val, str)]`

`print(output)`

Output:

`['plants', 'steak']`

Answer (score 0):

Just change the function to this:

```
def compare_lists_same(list3, list4):
    list3 = [i for i in list3 if type(i)==str]
    list4 = [i for i in list4 if type(i)==str]
    common =[j for j in list4 if j in list3]
    return common
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a function that loops through the list and checks the type of each value before printing it. Something like this:

```
def print_list_of_strings(list_to_print):
    s = "["
    for value in list_to_print:
        if type(value) != 'int':
            s += '"' + value + '", '
    s = s[:len(s) - 2] + ']'
    print(s) # or return s
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
a = ['beef','chicken','steak','fish','plants', 1, 2]
b = ['plants','steak','cheese', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

a2 = []
b2 = []

for ele in a:
    if(type(ele)==str):
        a2.append(ele)
    else:
        pass
    
for ele in b:
    if(type(ele)==str):
        b2.append(ele)
    else:
        pass

print(a2)
print(b2)
```